# Не выводится звук на windows 11 при помощи MessageBeep

Tags: c#, аудио

У меня в задании нужно написать код, который будет воспроизводить системный звук. В моём случае это звук Windows 11. Я пробовал через MessageBeep. В итоге никакого звука не было, сначала думал, что проблема в коде, потом начал склоняться к самой особенности ОС Windows 11. Код будет ниже

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace lb23
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            [DllImport("user32.dll")] static extern Boolean MessageBeep(UInt32 beepType);
            MessageBeep(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Короче вот мужики, помогите, пожалуйста, что за проблема и как решить можно.

Comment: У вас метод внутри метода... нельзя так делать. Расположите методы внутри класса и будет все работать.